# Weird normalize in Unity Mono

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

Normalizing a vector2 causes a weird round effect.I tried dir/dir.magnitude as well but same result,there should be something obvious that I'm missing but what it is?

```
        Debug.Log(start);

        dir = (Vector2.zero - start);

        Debug.Log(dir);

        dir = dir.normalized;

        Debug.Log(dir);

        /*Output
            (19.7, 452.1)
            (-19.7, -452.1)
            (0.0, -1.0)
         */
```

Comment: That looks fine to me, since Debug.Log(Vector) rounds to the nearest 0.1 value. So dir.x can be negative 0.04f and it will still beprinted as 0.0. Are what value would you expect?

Comment: Considering the values would be 0.04 and 0.999 that’s quite expected when rounded. With a debugger or writing out more decimals you can check if that is the result

Comment: So it's not the ".normalized" rounding the numbers Debug.Log is rounds them.Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 0):

**Debug.Log(Vector) always rounds to the nearest 0.1 value.** So dir.x can be negative 0.04f and it will still beprinted as 0.0.

If you run this code:

```
    Vector2 direction = new Vector2(-19.7f, -452.1f);
    Debug.Log("direction=" + direction);

    direction = direction.normalized;
    Debug.Log("direction normalized=" + direction.normalized);
    Debug.Log("direction normalized.x=" + direction.normalized.x);
    Debug.Log("direction normalized.y=" + direction.normalized.y);
```

it will print

```
direction=(-19.7, -452.1)
direction normalized=(0.0, -1.0)
direction normalized.x=-0.04353312
direction normalized.y=-0.999052
```

You can see that in Debug.Log(...) direction.x is rounded to 0.0, because it is approximately -0.04353312.